# Linked List Cycle , leetcode problem 142, i cannot find the cycle

Tags: java

**why is this not detecting the cyle,someone help**
[i want to get 2 that means 2nd node from this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ovlr.png)
[this is another example, i want to get 1st node(1) here;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6GQ0.png)

its not detecting the cycles;i dont understand, the next time hare and turtle meets next node of that should be the node where the cycle is pointed

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean cycle(ListNode head){
        ListNode hare=head;
        ListNode turtle=head;

        while(hare.next!=null && hare!=null){
            hare=hare.next.next;
            turtle=turtle.next;
            if(hare==turtle){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public ListNode detectCycle(ListNode head) {
        ListNode hare=head;
        ListNode turtle=head;
        if(cycle(head)){
            hare=hare.next.next;
            turtle=turtle.next;
            if(hare==turtle){
                hare=head;
                return hare.next;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

please help someone!

Comment: Do not use the `dsa` tag.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: ohh okay sorry;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not applied the algorithm correctly: in the second phase of the algorithm -- once the cycle has been detected -- you need to:

1. have one of the two references (let's say `hare`) start from the point where the cycle was detected, and only have the other start at the head. But your code is having both references start at the `head`, not knowing anymore at which node the cycle was detected.
2. Both references should move with *equal speeds*, but your code is still moving `hare` with double speed in that second phase
3. Both references should *keep doing* that until they meet, but your code does no have this loop and just makes both references move once.
4. If after this single move the two references have not coincided, you still return `null`, even though you had detected a cycle. Obviously when there is a cycle, there is a first node in that cycle, and you must return it. `null` is not an option.
5. If both references *do* coincide after this single move, your code resets `hare` to `head` and returns `hare.next`. So the code **always** returns `head.next` or `null`. It cannot return anything else. Obviously, any other node *could* potentially be the first node of the cycle, so your code will fail on such inputs.

Here is the correction of your code, with comments where I made changes:

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode cycle(ListNode head) { // Return type is ListNode now
        ListNode hare = head;
        ListNode turtle = head;

        while (hare != null && hare.next != null) { // Order of the conditions matters!
            hare = hare.next.next;
            turtle = turtle.next;
            if (hare == turtle) {
                return hare; // The caller needs this node!
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public ListNode detectCycle(ListNode head) {
        ListNode hare = cycle(head); // We need to remember where we ended up
        if (hare != null) {
            ListNode turtle = head;
            while (hare != turtle) { // Need to loop 
                hare = hare.next; // ...and step at equal speeds now
                turtle = turtle.next;
            }
            return hare;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```